# IceFaces fileUpload by multiple users at a time, working as sequentially rather concurrently

Tags: file-upload, icefaces, jsf-1.2

Me have a scenario , where a (zip)file is uploaded from UI by a user and the file is copied on to the server and unzipped to a destination folder.
  I am using JSF 1.2 and ICE Faces 1.8.2.GA_P01_8 in my application. When more than one user upload the zip file , the upload is happening (one after other) sequentially. I.e. not processing concurrent zip file uploads.

Me not sure how to handle the situation without upgrading the JSF and ICEFaces version.
I would be very thankful if any body helps in this regard.

Thank you.
~Sha

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it! What is working? What is not working? What is the behavior you like to have?

Comment: One more question , how to integrate appache fileUpload with JSF 1.2 ... all example i found with doPost() where as in managed bean we cant have doPost() then how to get uploaded File name from request Object ?

Comment: Michael , Thank you for your reply....When more than two users upload files accessing my application portal , at the back end those files upload one after other finished uploading ....but not simultaneously...how to make many users upload's can done concurrently